# Google Maps API - Default marker inaccurate when zoomed out

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am having an issue with the default marker, it seems to be offset when zoomed out. I've had a good look around on here but can only find answers to custom marker images and setting the anchor point on the image. I'm using google's default marker image.

http://thecompleteanimaldirectory.com

This is the website in question, you will notice that the maps in the book will be inaccurate once you zoom out, for example the customer in the Isle of White will end up in Germany!

However, on this page, the maps are accurate.

http://www.thecompleteanimaldirectory.com/search.php?category=dog&area=

```
geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
                                var mapOptions = {
                                    center: { lat: 32.00, lng: 15.00},
                                    zoom: 8
                                };


                                function initialize() {
                                    var map20 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas_barrie"), mapOptions);

                                    function codeAddress20() {
                                        var address20 = "11 Ashey Park, Ashey Road Ryde, I.O.W, PO33 4AL";


                                        geocoder.geocode( { "address": address20}, function(results, status) {
                                            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                                                map20.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                                                var marker20 = new google.maps.Marker({
                                                    map: map20, 
                                                    position: results[0].geometry.location,
                                                });
                                            } else {
                                                map20.setZoom(0);
                                            }
                                        });
                                    }
                                    codeAddress20();
```

Code is identical for both pages, I have gone as far as to style the maps the same on both pages but no luck. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Please provide a [**Minimal**, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an CSS-issue.

Source of the problem is this rule in main.css, which also applies to images in the map:

```
        .booklet .b-wrap-right img,
        #book-right-side img {
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 10px;
            right: 15px;
            height: 30px;
        }
```

add this rule to override it:

```
  .right-book .gm-style img{
            bottom: 0;
            right: 0;
            position:relative;
            height:auto;
  }
```